Character of dense subspace of regular space
Define the character of a topological space $X$ at $x$ to be the minimal cardinality of a base at $x$, denoted by $\chi(x,X)$.
Suppose $M$ is a dense subspace of a regular space $X$, prove that $\chi(x,M)=\chi(x,X)$.
My attempt is: obviously $\chi(x,M)\le\chi(x,X)$. Assume $\chi(x,M)<\chi(x,X)$, then there exists a base $\{U\cap M\}_{x\in U}$ at $x$ in $M$ such that $\{U\}_{x\in U}$ is not a base at $x$ in $X$. It follows that there exists an open subset $V\ni x$ such that for every base set $U\cap M$ we have $U\cap M\subseteq V\cap M$ but $U\nsubseteq V$. So we can choose a $y\in M$ with $y\in U\setminus V$.
But then how to use that $M$ is dense and $X$ is regular?
